# Returning value with the same constness as the parameter

Tags: c++, constants

I have a function with these overloads:

```
A& f(B& b)
{
    return b.a;
}

const A& f(const B& b)
{
    return b.a;
}
```

The return statement can be a much more complicated logic which returns some value that is const if `b` is const. For example, `B` is a container of containers (possibly with even deeper nesting) and we are searching for one element. In this case, copying the function is not a good idea. Is there any alternatives for achieving the same result?

I can think of some solutions, but I don't really like them.

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T& b) -> decltype(b.a)
{
    return b.a;
}
```

It works but becomes complicated if that `b.a` is not so trivial (as in the with in the containers).

```
A& f(B& b)
{
    return b.a;
}

const A& f(const B& b)
{
    return f(const_cast<B&>(b));
}
```

This also works but if feels like a hack. Is there a simple and clean solution?

Comment: What about `A& f(B& b) { return f(const_cast<const B&>(n)); }`? Adding `const` is not a hack, and you still get all the guarantees. I am assuming that the function can always work on const input, which the question seems to imply.

Comment: Then I would have to const_cast the output, so it's basically the same. But yes, maybe that's safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement non-const version in terms of const version, not the other way round (as you did).

```
A& f(B& b)
{
    return const_cast<A&>(f(static_cast<B const&>(b)));
}
```

It looks *a bit* safer from mutability point of view.

As for the template version, how about this:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T& b) -> std::conditional_t<std::is_const<T>{}, A const&, A&>
{
    return b.a;
}
```

If `std::conditional_t` (C++14) is not supported, then use `std::conditional`:

```
typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>{}, A const&, A&>::type
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hm, I think you're right, the non-const version should be implemented in terms of the const one... I always get confused about which way is right.

Comment: Shouldn't `is_const<T>{}` for `std::conditional` be `std::is_const<T>::value`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: It has an implicit conversion function : `constexpr operator bool() const`. That will be invoked implicitly and will get `value` automatically.

Comment: If we have C++14, then a simple `decltype(auto)` return type works well.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `f` doesn't mutate the data, then the `const_cast` is not a hack, but rather a perfectly legitimate solution.

The typical example for this is `strchr`, which finds a character in a string. We *know* that this doesn't mutate, but it's perfectly sensible to allow a mutable string to be mutated by offering a non-const overload. However, the non-const version can happily be implemented in terms of the const overload.

Bear in mind that it's not a violation to use `const_cast`. It's only a violation to mutate a constant *object*.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
template<typename B>
struct Return_type { typedef A &Type; };

template<typename B>
struct Return_type<B const &> { typedef A const &Type; };

template<typename B>
typename Return_type<B>::Type f(B &&b)
{
    return b.a;
}
```

EDIT:

C++14 will have function return type deduction, so this should work:

```
template<typename T>
auto &f(T &&b)
{
    return b.a;
}
```

gcc 4.8.1 already compiles it.

Comment: The new-style typedef `using Type=A const &;` looks much better.

Comment: Doesn't `auto` discard const-ness?

Comment: +1 for the C++14 solution. I thought of that too, but I only considered solutions valid in C++11.

Comment: @Hulk: Only for values, not for references. For example in `int const x = 4; auto y = x`, the type of `y` will be `int`, not `int const`. But in `int const x = 4; auto &y = x`, the type of `y` will be `int const &`.